# Missing Frameworks after installing VS 2012

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

So I have two machines I have installed 2012 on and they do not have identical frameworks installed on them the correct one looks like this

Machine A Screenshot:
[image: Working]

But the incorrect one looks like this

Machine B Screenshot:
[image]

Note that the following packages are missing from the second screenshot/machine B

- Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Client Profile
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4 Extended

Because of this, when I open up a 2010 project in 2010 I get this error now

[image]

The machine that is not working is missing the 2.0 framework in Visual studio 2010 and 2012

[image]

But I have installed the .net 2.0 framework and still get the same message and the framework is not showing up in Visual studio 2012 and 2010.

[image]

Anyone know why and what I can do to fix this issue ?

Comment: The screenshot above doesn't show the .NET Framework 2.0; are you sure you have installed it? It does show the 3.5, and also gives you the option to target that, so that at least seems consistent.

Comment: In windows 7 the 3.5 framwork installs the 2.0 framework through control panel

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the .NET Framework 2.0 and 3.5 (that's the one your project is asking), this depends of your Windows version, but for Windows 7 and newer, you need to open the Program and Features applet of the Control Panel, and there click on Turn Windows features on or off, then enable the .NET Framework 3.5, in earlier Windows versions you need to download and install them from Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall everything related to framework 4, do not touch any other version. Reinstall framework 4. It should also install/update/repair v2.

Comment: I installed and reinstalled and reinstalled frameworks still same result

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: a wild guess - did you try restarting after you uninstalled and then second time - after you installed frameworks?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: Ok, how about this - uninstall both vs 2010 and 2012, then all the frameworks, then restart, and try to install everything again. There must be a workaround. BTW, did you try VS 2010 repair as suggested in the above answer?

Comment: the work around was fdisk and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Should be either through Windows updates (it will detect what you are missing on the next scheduled update) or by re-launching Visual Studio installation and I believe there is an option to repair the existing installation. Hope that helps.